# Is there a good command line tool for converting to and from FLAC audio format?

Tags: software-rec, audio, conversion

Ideally, I want to convert from MP3 to FLAC and back. I also need to be able to script this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The fundamental tool for sound format conversions and simple transformations is [SoX, the Swiss Army knife of sound-processing programs](http://sox.sourceforge.net/).

```
sox foo.mp3 foo.flac
```

If you're running Debian, support for writing MP3 in `sox` is broken in *lenny* and *squeeze* (and as far as I know the same problem affects Ubuntu 10.04 and 10.10). [This bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=382275) was fixed in early March 2011, so grabbing the latest source (or grabbing a binary for `sox` 14.3.1-1build1 or newer) and recompiling it should work.

An alternative for encoding to `.mp3` is [`lame`](http://lame.sourceforge.net/). It doesn't read `.flac`, but you can use `sox` or [`flac`](http://flac.sourceforge.net/) to convert from `.flac` to `.wav` and then `lame` from `.wav` to `.mp3`.

```
flac -d foo.flac -c | lame - foo.mp3
```

Answer (score 7):

[sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) version 13 and up supports FLAC, along with [many other formats](http://sox.sourceforge.net/soxformat.html). sox can do [many things](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) to an audio file, not just convert from one format to another. It is to audio what [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is to graphics.

Comment: great analogy, man. that got you an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

It's called `flac`, oddly enough.  It's somewhat painful to use, or was back when I scripted a transcoding job with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course use SoX, as other people already mentioned, but I suggest using [`lame`](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) and [`flac`](https://xiph.org/flac/):

Your first question is going from `.mp3` to `.flac` (see below why this is usually a bad idea):

```
lame --decode <file>.mp3 - | flac -o <file>.flac -
```

This will use WAV headers, which has limitations when it comes to very long files (four hours or more long sound files, etc.)

Your second question is how to go from `.flac` to `.mp3`:

```
flac -d -c <file>.flac | lame - <file>.mp3
```

These settings assume default quality levels, etc. Read the man page of `lame` and/or `flac` to get a better idea how to tweak them.

---

Now, it might just be, that you have very long recordings, which you then want to re-encode into a lossy format. This was one of my use cases, and I came up with this:

Going from `.flac` to `.mp3` using default quality settings:

```
flac -d --force-raw-format --endian=little --sign=signed <file>.flac -c | lame -r -s 48 - <file>.mp3
```

This assumes the raw format is a PCM data. Sample rate 48kHz, two channels. Each sample is 16bit, little endian, signed integer.

Encoding process of `lame` is using default quality settings here, which might be not sophisticated enough for you, mind you.

---

It should be noted, that it makes no sense making a FLAC file out of an MP3 file, because the MP3 is already lossy encoded.

Going from MP3 -> FLAC and then FLAC -> MP3 makes no sense, as the quality will be impaired from the first, original MP3 encoding step.

However I assume you have a *reasonable* use-case for this...